# Couldn't find User with id=edit in rails tutorial chapter 9

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails. I am following Michael Hartl's railstutorial book. In chapter 9, when I tried to edit the user profile it won't work. 
/user/4/edit renders the edit page
But when I click settings inside the user profile which should render the edit page, it gets routed to        /user//edit
and the following error is shown:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show
Couldn't find User with id=edit

I know it will be a small error but I cant figure it out. So thanks for any help in advance.

Here are my files

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def new
@user=User.new
end

def create 
@user = User.new(params[:user])
if @user.save
  sign_in @user
  flash[:success] = "Welcome!"
  redirect_to @user
else
  render 'new'
end
end

def edit
@user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update
@user = User.find(params[:id])
if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
  flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
  sign_in @user
  redirect_to @user
else
 render 'edit'
end
end

end
```

_header.html.erb

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="container">
  <%= link_to "project",root_path, id: "logo" %>    
<nav>
  <ul class="nav pull-right">
    <li><%= link_to "Home",    root_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Help",    help_path %></li>

        <% if signed_in? %>
          <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
          <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Account <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><%= link_to "Profile", user_path(current_user) %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(@current_user) %></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li>
                <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>

    <% else %>
      <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path%></li>
    <% end %>

  </ul>
</nav>
 </div>
</div>
</header>
```

sessions_helper.rb

```
module SessionsHelper

def sign_in(user)
  cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  self.current_user = user
end

def signed_in?
  !current_user.nil?
end

def current_user=(user)
  @current_user = user
end

def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end

def sign_out
  self.current_user = nil
  cookies.delete(:remember_token)
end

end
```

edit.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title,'Edit user') %>
<h1>Update your profile</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">

    <%= form_for (@user) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>

    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>

    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm password" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

    <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>

  <% end %>

  <%= gravatar_for @user %>
  <a href="http://gravatar.com/emails" target="_blank"> Change </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

routes.rb

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do

resources :users
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

root to: 'static_pages#home'

match '/signup',   to: 'users#new', via: [:get, :post]
match '/signin',   to: 'sessions#new', via: [:get]
match '/signout',  to: 'sessions#destroy', via: [:delete]

match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help', via: [:get, :post]
match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: [:get, :post]
match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about', via: [:get, :post]
end
```

sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def new
end

def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    sign_in user
    redirect_to user
  else
    flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination"
    render 'new'
  end
end

def destroy
  sign_out
  redirect_to root_path
end

end
```

Comment: Can you please puts the params you are receiving in edit action

Comment: also, look at your log to see the raw params. For example: `Processing SearchesController#index (for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-27 09:56:35) [GET]
  Parameters: {"search"=>{"query"=>"yo"}}`

Comment: In the error, parameters is shown as   {"id" => "edit"}. Is this the params receiving in edit action?

Answer (score 3):

Change this

```
<li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(@current_user) %></li>
```

to this

```
<li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
```

You can only use variables that you have access to in the controller method that is being used to render the header. Your `show` controller only declares `@user`, not `@current_user`, so when the header is rendered the url that is created has nothing for the `user_id`. If use `current_user`, the `current_user` method from your `SessionsHelper` will be called, the current user will be returned and your url should have the `user_id` in it.

Here is the github account for the Hartl tutorial's sample app. It might be good practice to be able to go through it and compare it to your own code, and find where you have deviated. There might be some things different because you haven't completed the tutorial yet, but you are far enough along that it should be mostly all the same:  https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app

Comment: I tried that too. But now also the same error occurs. The error is highlighted as the 'show' method in users controller. This is the error line:  @user = User.find(params[:id]). Why isnt the user id passed to the url? Instead it takes id=edit.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are saying.

Comment: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show                Couldn't find User with id=edit     This error is still shown when I try to reach edit page

Comment: It sounds like a problem with your routes. Your `routes.rb` file looks fine. Did you change it recently? If you have changed it you need to restart the rails server for the changes to take affect. Restart the server, and run `rake routes` and make sure there is only one path going to `users#edit`, and that the path is `GET users/:id/edit`

Comment: Ya there is only one path. In the header, when I click 'profile' also it says that "the action 'index' could not be found for users controller". I think the problem is with current_user. These 2 links contains current_user.

Comment: Yes, according to your tutorial, you are missing a line in your `current_user` method in the `SessionsHelper`, it should be this: ` def current_user
    remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
  end`

Comment: In the video, that line was absent. Anyway when I provided that line the following error was raised:        undefined method `encrypt' for #<Class:0x007f6188ca6660>

Comment: Can you please take a look at the code now? I have made changes and now edit page can be seen by clicking settings. But now when I click signout it is redirected to root path but header renders previous options such as users and account itself instead of sign in

Comment: I'd have to see your `Sessions#destroy` method, I can't see anything else that is wrong with your sign out process at the moment. But I recommend you just go through Hartl's app and try to troubleshoot on your own. I added the link to the answer.

Comment: signout was working until I corrected the previous error. But now I think the method sign_out has some error. When I signout it is only redirected to home page.