# railstutorial.org "settings" link broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am working through Michael Hartl's railstutorial. My problem is `/user/1/edit` renders perfectly, but using edit_user_path(current_user) doesn't.

I've checked for typos, done some searching, [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805135/couldnt-find-user-with-id-edit-in-rails-tutorial-chapter-9/20805848#20805848) seemed like it might be the same issue, but the answer didn't get my link working.  Right now, I am trying to diff my code with [Michael's](https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app).

Let me know if there's anything other code that would help.
Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

**output of rake routes:**

```
    $ bundle exec rake routes
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                             Controller#Action
     password_resets_new GET    /password_resets/new(.:format)          password_resets#new
    password_resets_edit GET    /password_resets/edit(.:format)         password_resets#edit
account_activations_edit GET    /account_activations/edit(.:format)     account_activations#edit
                    root GET    /                                       static_pages#home
                    help GET    /help(.:format)                         static_pages#help
                   about GET    /about(.:format)                        static_pages#about
                 contact GET    /contact(.:format)                      static_pages#contact
                  signup GET    /signup(.:format)                       users#new
                   login GET    /login(.:format)                        sessions#new
                         POST   /login(.:format)                        sessions#create
                  logout DELETE /logout(.:format)                       sessions#destroy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                        users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)                        users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                    users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)               users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                    users#show
                         PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                    users#update
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                    users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                    users#destroy
 edit_account_activation GET    /account_activations/:id/edit(.:format) account_activations#edit
         password_resets POST   /password_resets(.:format)              password_resets#create
      new_password_reset GET    /password_resets/new(.:format)          password_resets#new
     edit_password_reset GET    /password_resets/:id/edit(.:format)     password_resets#edit
          password_reset PATCH  /password_resets/:id(.:format)          password_resets#update
                         PUT    /password_resets/:id(.:format)          password_resets#update
              microposts POST   /microposts(.:format)                   microposts#create
               micropost DELETE /microposts/:id(.:format)               microposts#destroy
```

added relevant log entry.

> Started GET "/edit_user_path(current_user)" for 76.186.33.24 at
>   2014-12-11 13:59:32 +0000
>
> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
>   "/edit_user_path(current_user)"):   web-console (2.0.0.beta3)
>   lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:22:in `middleware_call'
>
>   web-console (2.0.0.beta3)
>   lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in`call'   actionpack
>   (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in
>   `call'   railties (4.2.0.beta2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in`
>   call_app'   railties (4.2.0.beta2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in
>   `block in call'   activesupport (4.2.0.beta2)
>   lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in`block in tagged'
>   activesupport (4.2.0.beta2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in
>   `tagged'   activesupport (4.2.0.beta2)
>   lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in`tagged'   railties
>   (4.2.0.beta2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'   actionpack
>   (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in`
>   call'   rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
>
>   rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in`call'   activesupport
>   (4.2.0.beta2)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in
>   `call'   rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in`call'   actionpack
>   (4.2.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:103:in `call'
>
>   rack (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in`call'   railties
>   (4.2.0.beta2) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'   railties
>   (4.2.0.beta2) lib/rails/application.rb:161:in`call'   rack
>   (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'   rack
>   (1.6.0.beta) lib/rack/lint.rb:49:in`_call'   rack (1.6.0.beta)
>   lib/rack/lint.rb:37:in `call'   rack (1.6.0.beta)
>   lib/rack/showexceptions.rb:24:in`call'   rack (1.6.0.beta)
>   lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:33:in `call'   rack (1.6.0.beta)
>   lib/rack/chunked.rb:54:in`call'   rack (1.6.0.beta)
>   lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'   rack (1.6.0.beta)
>   lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in`service'
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in
>   `service'
>
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in`
>   run'
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in
>   `block in start_thread'
>
> Rendered
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
>   (1.6ms)   Rendered
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rails4/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (37.1ms)
>   76.186.33.24 - - [11/Dec/2014:13:59:32 +0000] "GET /500 HTTP/1.1" 500 1477 0.0647
>
> routes.rb
>
> ```
>     Rails.application.routes.draw do
>   get 'password_resets/new'
>
>   get 'password_resets/edit'
>
>   get 'account_activations/edit'
>
>   root                'static_pages#home'
>   get    'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
>   get    'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
>   get    'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
>   get    'signup'  => 'users#new'
>   get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
>   post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
>   delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
>   resources :users
>   resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
>   resources :password_resets, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
>   resources :microposts,          only: [:create, :destroy]  
> end
> ```
>
> _header.html.erb
>
> ```
> <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
>   <div class="container">
>     <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
>     <nav>
>       <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
>         <li><%= link_to "Home",   root_path %></li>
>         <li><%= link_to "Help",   help_path %></li>
>         <% if logged_in? %>
>           <li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>
>           <li class="dropdown">
>             <a href='#' class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
>               Account <b class="caret"></b>
>             </a>
>             <ul class="dropdown-menu">
>               <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
>               <li><%= link_to "Settings", 'edit_user_path(current_user)' %></li>
>               <li class="divider"></li>
>               <li>
>                 <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: "delete" %>
>               </li>
>             </ul>
>           </li>
>           <% else %>
>         <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
>         <% end %>
>       </ul>
>     </nav>
>   </div>
> </header>
> ```

Comment: what's the error? also post what returns when you run `rake routes` in console.

Comment: also a note: `edit_user_path(current_user)` should not be in string as you have it in your code

Comment: @rmagnum2002 all it tells me is 
"The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
"

Comment: don't put the path in string, it should be `<%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %>`, I don't see any other problem that might brake it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
<%= link_to "Settings", 'edit_user_path(current_user)' %>
```

should become this:

```
<%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %>
```

Your logs shows that app looks for `/edit_user_path(current_user)` because you send it as a string and normally you don't have this path. See line first of your logs `Started GET "/edit_user_path(current_user)"`

it should be `Started GET "/users/1/edit"`

Comment: just made that change, reset my webrick, no dice.

Comment: can you join this chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66663/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-27424476-railstutorial-org-settings-link-broke

Comment: also double check, cause you got the routes properly set up.. just double check the link.

Comment: seems I don't have enough rep to chat.

Comment: got it.. I reset my webrick, but didn't refresh the page.  thank you!